# Send and Receive DIME Attachments Java

Tags: java, weblogic, attachment

I see that this question has been asked couple of times, but I am not able to understand the final verdict that whether it is possible to send and receive attachments in DIME using JAVA and if yes, how ?

I have a SOA Suite enabled Weblogic server, but it seems BPEL processes are not able to send/receive DIME attachments and that is the reason why, we have to look out for JAVA options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a ton !

Comment: *"I see that this question has been asked couple of times..."* Please link to the related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, SOA Suite 11g does not support DIME attachments. I'm guessing you are looking to make a SOAP call with DIME attachments. AFAIK neither CXF nor Axis2 supports DIME.

On the other hand, Axis1 seems to support it. 
http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/client-side-axis.html#CallConfiguration

I guess you can generate a SOAP client and call it with a java activity. This SOAP client would be built with Axis1.

Sounds difficult though..